# Event Storming: How to phrase a command initiated by an actor, and where to put it software-wise

Tags: domain-driven-design

In Event Storming, there are "Commands" (blue sticky notes) which are, in most cases, triggered by an Actor.
How should these commands be named, prosa-wise, especially in relation to the actor? Something like Visitor -> "klicks checkout button" or, Visitor -> "go to checkout" ..?

So: what is the intended naming scheme in terms of grammar and sentence construction of a command?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you name them the same way you would name anything else: by giving them meaningful names.  See also  [An actor model implementation in C# using TPL DataFlow](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/15/an-actor-model-implementation-in-c-using-tpl-dataflow/).

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I especially refer to the terminology used in "Event Storming", where an actor typically means a person or something who initiates a command.

Comment: I don't think there's any magic here.  You need meaningful names; pick your own.  There's no predefined naming convention here; this is business domain storming.  Use names that are meaningful to the business domain.  See also http://ziobrando.blogspot.com/2013/11/introducing-event-storming.html#.VLU7KCvF9fw

Comment: you should really give some more detail here - you're using a bunch of terms in ways that are totally different than people use them typically just from reading this (actor, visitor, command, these have common well known definitions none of which make sense the way you're using the words)

Comment: There is no "right way" to write Blue Stickies. The trick is to spark the right type of conversation when needed. Filtering of technical interaction should have already been happening at the Domain Event stage. What I am really concerned when asking about commands is the information needed by a given type of user actor in order to make this decision/issue this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may sound weird at first but try using "goal driven" names.

So instead of "klicks checkout button" rephrase it as what the actor wants to achieve. Say Visitor "reviews checkout page". You may decide to implement this as an on screen button but that comes later.

This simple trick of language stops you "implementing" too early in the design. "visitor clicks checkout button" could on really be implemented by a user with a mouse and GUI screen with a labeled button. Voice, gesture, etc. are ruled out of the design before you have even started.

Comment: perfect, thanks! Especially the last paragraph is exactly why I asked the question. Thanks again!